# Hide a rectangular block temporarily from the main window in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I created a nested rectangular block i.e. a rectangle inside a main rectangular block in QML. Now I have to hide the inner rectangular block on some operation and once the operation is finished make it visible again. I am trying the following:

```
Rectangle {
        id: window
        width: 450
        height: 550
        property bool isTopToolBarAreaVisible : true

    Rectangle {
        id: toolBarArea
        width: 1
        height: parent.height
        color: toolBarColor
        visible : isTopToolBarAreaVisible

        ToolButton {
                    contentItem: Text {
                        text: "Save as"                     
                    }
                    onClicked: {
                        ...
                        isTopToolBarAreaVisible = false // hide the inner rectangule
                        window.grabToImage(function(result) {
                            result.saveToFile(fileName);
                        }, Qt.size(window.width*2,window.height*2));
                        isTopToolBarAreaVisible = true // show the inner rectangle again
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

I created a boolean isTopToolBarArea to control the visibility but it does not work. Can anyone help.

Comment: Your inner rectangle with id `toolBarArea` doesn't have any `width` and `height`.

Comment: Also, the operation is rather short and you are not giving the UI-thread a chance to actually hide the rectangle (staying in the function)

Comment: @Aamir: The width and height is there, I didnt add it here for simplicity. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Amfasis In that case should there be a delay/ refresh added before hiding and grab call?

Comment: yes, the UI-thread should have time to update without the inner rectangle. But, possibly you can also move the inner Rectangle out of the item you are grabbing to image, such that this curiosity is not needed (and then use `anchor.left: window` and `anchor.top: window`)

Comment: Using a timer for delay re-show inner rectangle ~>=10ms interval is enough

Comment: you shouldn't execute tasks in the GUI thread, use either [WorkerScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-workerscript-workerscript.html) or some C++ analogue. And to avoid disambiguate use IDs, i.e. `window.isTopToolBarAreaVisible` even more if you use it from another/nester item.

Comment: @M.GalibUludag I added delay by adding a new function delayGrab(duration) before the call to window.grabToImage() but it does not work still. Can you please elaborate a bit more about the delay.

Comment: @user2695082 I added simple example https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/kunaxaxego.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. I'm hiding the `Rectangle` containing the `ToolButton` when `onClicked` is triggered and show it again inside the callback assigned to `grabToImage(callback, targetSize)`. Adding the `RowLayout` was just to make the `ToolButton` horizontally centered in the `Rectangle`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: window
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"

        Rectangle {
            id: toolBarArea
            width: parent.width
            height: 40
            color: "red"

            RowLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent

                ToolButton {
                    contentItem: Text { text: "Save as" }
                    onClicked: {
                        toolBarArea.visible = false
                        window.grabToImage(function(result) {
                            result.saveToFile("test.png")
                            toolBarArea.visible = true
                        }, Qt.size(window.width * 2, window.height * 2))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. The saved file test.png doesnt show the inner rectangle. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just calling your delayGrab() function inside your onClicked handler, that still won't work. You're delaying the work but not allowing the UI thread to continue running while it's waiting. If your function takes a long time, a worker thread would be preferable. But for fairly short tasks, a timer will work. The timer should look something like this:

```
Rectangle {
    ...
    Rectangle {
        ...
        ToolButton {
            onClicked: {
                isTopToolBarAreaVisible = false // hide the inner rectangle
                myTimer.start();
            }
        }

        Timer {
            id: myTimer
            interval: 10 // Adjust this as needed
            onTriggered: {
                window.grabToImage(function(result) {
                    result.saveToFile(fileName);
                    }, Qt.size(window.width*2,window.height*2));
                isTopToolBarAreaVisible = true // show the inner rectangle again
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately this is not working even after adding delay of 10000. Infact I can see the hiding of the toolbar at the top from the main rectangle but the image that is getting saved contains the top toolbar. I have started to doubt the function grabToImage which says it grabs the memory image of of the Item and that this is not a screenshot of the item. One more option I can think of is Cropping. Will it be possible to crop the top toolbar from the result.image and then save that cropped image in a file?